# Is there a way to redirect certain URLs to certain Browsers in Linux?

Tags: linux, url, firefox, browser, filter

I'm using Chrome as my default Browser under Ubuntu 12.10. 
I need to use firefox for business purposes (certain websites pertaining to my work only work with firefox). Is there a way to force ubuntu to use Firefox for certain types of URLs (maybe as defined by a regular expression) while maintaining Chrome as my default browser for all my other Tasks? Perhaps as a shell script running in the background? I'd like this to work system-wide, covering links from Chrome itself as well as PDFs/ODTs etc. pp. 
I have searched for solutions, but couldn't come up with anything besides OpenWith, a Firefox extension which adds a button to open certain links in other Browsers which would again require me to open Firefox beforehand which does not help me at all. 
Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [su].

Comment: Oh, sorry about that then... Will post my question there as well. Thank you.